# Select first two elements of each sublist in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,18,20]]
```

I want to create a new list that contains only the first two elements of each sublist in one line code only. For example:

```
b = [[1, 2], [6, 7], [11, 12], [16, 17]]
```

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
b = a[:][0:2]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to apply the same slice to each sublist:

```
b = [l[:2] for l in a]
```